# Idiomatic way to stop pylint complaining about flask route unused function names?

Tags: python, flask, pylint

My Python Flask application contains a lot of route definitions like

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
```

Then pylint complains

```
W: 72, 4: Unused variable 'index' (unused-variable)
```

which is technically correct.  I can't replace all the function names by `_`, say, because then Flask complains

```
AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: _
```

I could replace all the handler function names with their underscore-prefixed equivalents, i.e. change `index` to `_index`, etc..  Is there another idiomatic way of dealing with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use pylint_flask, but it doesn't work.

```
pylint --load-plugins pylint_flask makerpose/appserver.py
```

Adding `_` in front of methods' names solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look around for plugin on pylint for Flask? I hope it can help you, but this one seems to be something that might be helping you ( I say might, because I don't use Flask, nor have I had that problem) :
https://github.com/jschaf/pylint-flask#usage

Good Luck and let us know your result

Comment: This plugin does handle this problem and also doesn't help newer versions of Flask users. This problem continues unsolved everywhere I look.